# How should I build a report so that the dashboard acts like a filter?

Tags: dashboard, cognos, cognos-11

I want to create a drill-through function from a Cognos Analytics 11 Dashboard to a report. Although I have some experience with the dashboard-module, I'm pretty unfamiliar with reports. 
How should I build the report, so that the dashboard acts like a filter? Can this be achieved just by creating a report with a List, containing the same variables as those included in the dashboard?
Can someone guide me through the process?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this be achieved just by creating a report with a List, containing
>   the same variables as those included in the dashboard?

Yes, here is an IBM link that may also help

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_ca_dshb.doc/ca_drill_through_concept.html

Quick Summary/example

1) Create a report (a simple list to start) with filters

[Year] = ?Year?

[Month] = ?Month?

etc.

2) Create a dashboard with the elements year, month, etc

From the dashboard

Add new drill-through (the icon looks like an arrow over a bullseye target, near the trash can.  It will appear on the swing out menu when you click on the overall visualization in an area of whitespace)

Navigate to the report

The filters from the report will appear, match them to the dashboard columns

To test, run the dashboard.  Right click on the part of the visualization that represents a metric.  A swing out menu with an icon for drill through should be available.  Select that icon and it should go to the report